# Can anybody comment on django-wapi?

Tags: django, web-services

Aside for a few user guides found at http://fi.am/en/tag/django/2/ I have not managed to find much about WAPI.

I was wondering if anyone has had an experience using WAPI and django to create a web api?
I'm a little intimidated by the amount of magic these frameworks seem to do.

Are there any other good alternatives to creating a web api in python?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a decent guide to the django WAPI for building a restful API: http://fi.am/entry/building-a-website-api-with-django-part-2a-api-aut/